# express does not handle url like this "api/:htip/feedback"

Tags: node.js, express

I am using nodejs and express to create a web app.
I can handle "/api/healthtips/:htip", with codes as follow:

```
app.get('/api/healthtips/:htip', function (req, res) {
return HealthTipModel.find({"_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.htip)}, function (error, healthTip) {
    if (!error) {
        return res.send(healthTip);
    }
});
```

});

I check in the browser and json returns.

But I can not handle "api/:htip/feedback", with codes

```
app.post('api/:htip/feedback', function(req, res) {
var healthTip = HealthTipModel.find({"_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.htip)}, function(error, healthTip) {
    if (!error) {
        return healthTip;
    }
});
if (healthTip._id) {
    var healthTip = new HTipFeedbackModel({
        type: req.body.type,
        comment: req.body.comment,
        healthTip: healthTip._id
    });
}
```

});

when I use jquey.post to access this path, it returns 404.

Why? somebody gives me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just `return` because it's asynchronous.
You should use callbacks:

```
app.post('/api/:htip/feedback', function(req, res) {

  HealthTipModel.findById(req.params.htip, function(error, healthTip) {

    if (!error) {

        var newhealthTip = new HTipFeedbackModel({
            type: req.body.type,
            comment: req.body.comment,
            healthTip: healthTip._id
        })

        newhealthTip.save(function(error){

          if (!error) {
             res.send(healthTip);
          } else {    
            res.status(400).send('Cannot save')
          }

        });   

    } else {    
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  });

});
```